# Unable to mock RestTemplate using JUnit 5 in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, junit5, junit-jupiter

Trying to mock restTemplate postForEntity() but it is returning null instead of ResponseEntity object I am passing inside thenReturn().

Service Impl class

```
public ResponseEntity<Object> getTransactionDataListByAccount(Transaction transaction) {
    ResponseEntity<Object> transactionHistoryResponse = restTemplate.postForEntity(processLayerUrl, transaction, Object.class);        
    return new ResponseEntity<>(transactionHistoryResponse.getBody(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Inside Test class

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "test")
public class TransactionServiceImplTest {

    @MockBean
    private RestTemplate mockRestTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private TransactionServiceImpl transactionService;

    @Test 
    public void getTransactionDataListByAccountTest() throws Exception{
    
    Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
    transaction.setPosAccountNumber("40010020070401");
            
    ArrayList<Object> mockResponseObj = new ArrayList<Object>(); //filled with data

    ResponseEntity<Object> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<Object>(mockResponseObj, HttpStatus.OK);
    
    when(mockRestTemplate.postForEntity(
            ArgumentMatchers.anyString(), 
            ArgumentMatchers.eq(Transaction.class), 
            ArgumentMatchers.eq(Object.class))).thenReturn(responseEntity);
    

    // THROWING NullPointerException at this line.
    ResponseEntity<Object> actualResponse = transactionService.getTransactionDataListByAccount(transaction);

    
    System.out.println("--- Response ---");
    System.out.println(actualResponse);
}
```

Error

While executing test case, actual service is getting called. When it tries to invoke resttemplate inside service impl class it is returning null.

Trying to call getBody() on transactionHistoryResponse throwing  NullPointerException

Comment: Hi, please can you post the stack trace?

Comment: @PMah: Edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your mock setup, the matcher `ArgumentMatchers.eq(Transaction.class)` will only match if the argument you pass in is the `Class<Transaction>` object `Transaction.class`. This is not what you want; you want it to match anything of *type* `Transaction`. To do this, use `ArgumentMatchers.any(Transaction.class)`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30898813/5317869) has a good explanation.